# Why is my map merge function merging everything?

Tags: go, recursion, data-science

I have a rather simple Go program that determines if there are overlaps in someone's schedule of events. Essentially this is what it does:

We have 3 events, let's say for a grocery store:

```
            day   0  1  2  3  4  5     
apple sale        [-----------]
banana sale             [--------]
pickle sale                [-------------]
```

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type event struct {
    start int
    end int
    groups map[string]bool
}

func main(){
    //Create Events
    campaigns := []event{
        event{
            start: 0,
            end: 4,
            groups: map[string]bool{
                "apple sale": true,
            },
        },
        event{
            start: 2,
            end: 5,
            groups: map[string]bool{            
                "banna sale": true,         
            },
        },
        event{
            start: 3,
            end: 10,
            groups: map[string]bool{
                "pickle sale": true,
            },
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n-------------\n| Events    |\n-------------\n\n")

    for _, c := range campaigns {
        fmt.Printf("Name: ")
        for name, _ := range c.groups {
            fmt.Printf("%v, ", name)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nStart:%v\nEnd:%v\n\n", c.start, c.end)
    }

    overlaps := recursiveOverlaps(campaigns, make([]event, 0))

    fmt.Printf("\n-------------\n| Overlaps  |\n-------------\n\n")

    for _, c := range overlaps {
        fmt.Printf("Events: ")
        for name, _ := range c.groups {
            fmt.Printf("%v, ", name)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nStart:%v\nEnd:%v\n\n", c.start, c.end)
    }
}

func recursiveOverlaps(events []event, overlaps []event) []event {

    //pop comparisonEvent (first item in array)
    comparisonEvent, events := events[len(events)-1], events[:len(events)-1]


    if len(events) == 0 {//check base case
        return overlaps;
    }

    //Find overlaps
    for _, eventItem := range events {

        overlaping, overlapCase := overlapExists(comparisonEvent, eventItem)

        if overlaping {

            groups := mergeKeys(comparisonEvent.groups, eventItem.groups)

            switch overlapCase {

                case 1:
                    overlaps = append( overlaps, event{eventItem.start, eventItem.end, groups} )

                case 2:
                    overlaps = append( overlaps, event{comparisonEvent.start, comparisonEvent.end, groups} )

                case 3:
                    overlaps = append( overlaps, event{eventItem.start, comparisonEvent.end, groups} )

                case 4:
                    overlaps = append( overlaps, event{comparisonEvent.start, eventItem.end, groups} )
            }

            //reset groups so we don't get any funny business
            groups = map[string]bool{}

        }
    }

    return recursiveOverlaps(events, overlaps)
}

func overlapExists(a event, b event) (bool, int) {

    if between(a.start, a.end, b.start) && between(a.start, a.end, b.end) {
    // [----------]
    //    [-----]
        return true, 1
    }

    if between(b.start, b.end, a.start) && between(b.start, b.end, a.end) {
    //    [-----]
    // [----------]
        return true, 2
    }

    if between(a.start, a.end, b.start) {
    // [----------]
    //    [--------------
        return true, 3
    }

    if between(a.start, a.end, b.end) {
    //            [----------]
    //    --------------]
        return true, 4
    }

    return false, 0
}

func between(a, b, c int) bool {
    //is c between a and b?
    if c > a && c < b {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// Given two maps merge right into left
func mergeKeys(left, right map[string]bool) map[string]bool {
    for key, rightVal := range right {
        left[key] = rightVal
    }
    return left
}
```

The code *almost* works.... but the problem is, logically, I programmed this to only compare two events. Not three at a time. However, the result is this:

```
-------------
| Events    |
-------------

Name: apple sale,
Start:0
End:4

Name: banna sale,
Start:2
End:5

Name: car sale,
Start:3
End:10


-------------
| Overlaps  |
-------------

Events: banna sale, car sale, apple sale,
Start:3
End:4

Events: car sale, apple sale, banna sale,
Start:3
End:5

Events: banna sale, apple sale,
Start:2
End:4
```

Somehow I think the `mergeKeys()` function is doing something weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a link to it on my github if you want to run it for yourself: https://github.com/Goahnary/overlaps

Or you could always copy and paste the code into the go playground: https://play.golang.org/

Comment: Why not just take max([start dates]) and min([end dates]`)

Comment: I'm not following your logic

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/sz3Hxx3fSyT

Comment: Without looking at the rest of your code: note that `mergeKeys` *modifies* the left-side map, returning it as well. Your caller throws away the return value, which is sensible enough since it's just the first argument.

Comment: @torek I can see the modification... But I don't understand how the "groups" variable is accumulating other group names... Shouldn't the variable be overwritten every time?
Here's a link: https://play.golang.org/p/0otNm4EwBPv

Comment: @ShangjianDing I'm probably not understanding... But it has to find all overlaps. Not just the one.... I don't think I understand how your solution works though.

Comment: @torek I think maybe you meant to tell me this but I didn't get it. Maps in go are actually pointers to a heap. So when I was passing my map into the mergeKeys function I was modifying the actual map not a copy of it that was passed into the function.... Boy that was a doosie.

Comment: Right: even if you pass the value of a `map` variable, the value itself is a pointer to an underlying data structure, which lives elsewhere and is shared by other `map` variables that use the same underlying data. This is very similar to Go's slice headers: the slice header contains the pointer to the underlying array, and the length and capacity of the slice, but the underlying array is elsewhere, and potentially shared.

Comment: What is the reason for this? For performance? It seems like a bad idea to me. But I have faith it was done for a good reason.

Comment: Are you actually looking for a proper algorithm to solve this as a more general problem?  Generally speaking your task seems to be to find overlapping intervals (ranges) in a set of intervals, aka the intersection of a set of intervals.  There are a number of related and/or identical questions right here on SO.

Comment: @GregA.Woods My question is about the merging not working because, as I now understand, is because maps are actually pointers and not a value that is passes. i.e. the map is not duplicated when you pass it into the method. You will actually change the original map if you make changes to the variable in the function. The algorithm is working. Even if it isn't the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So I figured out what was going wrong:

#### maps in go are passed by reference.... kind of. Not really.

even though maps don't have a pointer in front of them... they are being passed by reference... kind of. Really they aren't but you can read more about that in [this article](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go), "there is no pass by reference in go" and [this article](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/30/if-a-map-isnt-a-reference-variable-what-is-it), "if a map isn't a reference variable what is it". I will give you this excerpt from it to clarify what is happening:

> A map value is a pointer to a runtime.hmap structure.

Even though the maps aren't being passed by reference but by value... The original map variable you passed into the function gets modified. This means when I was mutating the left map in my mergeKeys function I was actually changing the comparisonEvent.groups map as well.

To account for this I created a trash map that I could mutate and have no consequences:

```
if overlaping {

    trashMap := make(map[string]bool)
    for key, value := range comparisonEvent.groups {
        trashMap[key] = value
    }
    
    groups := mergeKeys(trashMap, eventItem.groups)

    switch overlapCase {
    
        case 1:
            overlaps = append( overlaps, event{eventItem.start, eventItem.end, groups} )

        case 2:
            overlaps = append( overlaps, event{comparisonEvent.start, comparisonEvent.end, groups} )

        case 3:
            overlaps = append( overlaps, event{eventItem.start, comparisonEvent.end, groups} )

        case 4:
            overlaps = append( overlaps, event{comparisonEvent.start, eventItem.end, groups} )
    }
}
```

I'm still open to discussion and better solutions before I accept this answer. I hope this helps someone out there!

Comment: "maps in go are passed by reference" this is plain **wrong**. Everything in Go is passed by value, nothing can be passed "by reference" because there is no notion of "reference" in Go. Maps in Go have reference semantics which is different to "are passes by reference" but lead also to the observed behaviour. Never think about "pass by reference" in Go. There is no such thing and using this term just leads to confusion.

Comment: You are correct. I seemed to have skimmed over that part and only took what information helped me solve the problem at hand. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @volker could you consider upvoting now that I've corrected my answer?